# How do some questions get "out of control"?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am not complaining.

I just want to understand how it works; I asked one question a couple days ago and compared to other questions around the same period, the one I asked (I won't link it; you can investigate me if you want to find out which one it is) has shot up like a weed, with views and posts far out of range of other questions.

Did someone share it on a couple of social networks, or did it get put on a blog, or is it just that some questions are more "fun" to debate and answer than others?

I'd like to know because it is striking to me how much of an outlier it appears.

Comment: When I investigated you, I found out that your dog likes to eat and drink gross stuff :p

Comment: @nxx - that is true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the sidebar of most pages, there's a list of *Hot Network Questions*, and this list is reproduced across the entire Stack Exchange network. As of this moment, your question is on it. I can't say for certain when your question got on the list, but it was very likely getting on that list that provoked the large number of votes, posts, and views.

Comment: Thanks, that seems reasonable.

Comment: @Josh The Hot Questions list is referred to colloquially as the Multicollider, and the act of getting on to it is sometimes called "getting multicollidered".

Comment: Well then, apparently I got multicollidered.  I'm gonna go lay down for a while.

Comment: And what makes a sentence get multicollidered?